# How do I store a resource path?

Tags: c#, image

The program I'm making is pretty hard to explain since it's for a very specific personal use so I'll use an example to make it easy to understand:

I have a class in the project named `Person` that stores an image and a name of a person.
All images are stored in the project resources.

**How do I save the resource path/name so that I can reuse it on the main program (not the `Person` class) ?**

For exemple if I create a new `Person` object in the main program:

```
Person p = new Person("Michael", Project.Properties.Resources.image);
```

As what type of variable do I save the path in the `Person` class?

```
public Person(string name, ??? image)
```

Note that I will need to reuse this image later,

for exemple:

```
this.imageBox.Image = p.image;
```

I tried using the `Image` and `Bitmap` objects but it just changed the `imageBox` to be blank (I think it sets the `imageBox.Image` to `null`. Also, I'm pretty sure that using `Bitmap` will copy the Image's data and use more memorey for no reason)

I also tried using `Image.FromFile` and inserting the path as a string but it didn't work.

Comment: @M463 No idea what do you mean... these images are stored as resources in the project. Got it fixed though, thanks anyway

Comment: I missed the part *All the pictures are stored in the project resources.*  Glad you got it fixed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be messing around with paths if you mean to use resources. They are embedded into the assembly and can be reused from there.

The easiest way to access them is by using the generated resources class, `Project.Properties.Resources.Picture`. The type of the variable will be an `Image`.

```
public Person(string name, Image picture)
```

If you want to, you can even [access the resource by extracting it by hand from the assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287526(v=vs.71).aspx), but that seems to much for this case as far as I can tell.

Comment: Tried again using Image now and it turns out that I forgot to copy the content of  the `Image` var in the constructor of the class, so the property was null all this time and thats why it didn't work.
Works now, Thanks